# Definition of suitable branch of $\log z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ D\subset\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{ 0\right\}  $ be a simply connected region and let $n\geq 2 $ be an integer. Let $a,b \in D $ such that $b^n=a$. I want to define a complex branch of $ \sqrt[n]{\cdot} $ so that $ \sqrt[n]{a}=b$.

So I assume the way to do it is to define $ \displaystyle\sqrt[n]{z}=e^{\frac{1}{n}\log z} $ with the correct branch of $\log $ such that for the argument $ a $ the function returns $ b $.

I know that theoretically there is such a branch of $\log$ but I'm not sure how to define it explicitly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no "correct branch"; Your choice of the branch cut determines the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Defining a branch of the logarithm from scratch.

Pick any continuous curve $\gamma: [0,\infty) \to \mathbb C$ with $\gamma(0) = 0 $ such that $ D := \mathbb C \setminus \gamma \left[[0,\infty) \right]$ is simply connected open set. A standard choice would be $\gamma(t) = t\omega$ for any $\omega \in \mathbb C^*$. Now, pick a $u \in D$ and some $v \in \mathbb C$ such that $e^v = u$. Then by the Cauchy integral theorem we can define a function $L: D \to \mathbb C $ such that $L(z) = \oint_{c} x^{-1}  \ \mathrm d x + v$ for any curve $c: [0,1] \to D$ with beginning point $u$ and end point $z$. The resulting $L$ is a branch of the logarithm with $L(u) = v$.

By changing $\gamma$ one can change the curve along which the branch is cut. By changing the pair $(u,v)$, one can changes the branch that the function $L$, i.e. the choice of values that $L$ picks.

### Using any branch of the logarithm to give the required branch of the $n^\text{th}$ root.

Suppose you are already given a branch $l: D \to \mathbb C$ of the logarithm and $a \in D$ and $a = b^n$ for some $b \in \mathbb C$. Define $f: D \to \mathbb C \ z \mapsto e^{\frac1n l(z)} $. $f$ is a branch of the $n^\text{th}$ root. Suppose that $a \neq 0$, otherwise there is nothing to prove as $b = 0$ and $f(a)  = b $.  Thus $b \neq 0$.

Let $c = f(a)$. As $c^n = a$ so $c \neq 0$. As $c^n = a = b^n$, so $\alpha^n = 1$ where $\alpha = bc^{-1}$. Thus $\alpha$ is an $n^\text{th}$ root of unity.  Now, define $g: D \to \mathbb C \ z \mapsto \alpha \cdot f(z)$. observe $g(a) = b c^{-1}c = b$. Additionally for all $u \in D$, note that:

$$
\begin{align}
 g(u)^n &= f(u)^n\alpha^n\\
 &= f(u)^n\\ 
&= u.
\end{align}
$$
Thus $g$ is a branch of the $n^\text{th}$ root because $f$ is.

Additionally, because $\exp$ is surjective onto $\mathbb C^*$ we may find some $\beta$ such that $e^\beta = \alpha$. Then define another function $m: D \to \mathbb C \ z \mapsto l(z) + n\beta$. Remark that for any $z \in D$, $\exp m(z) = e^{l(z)} \cdot {e^\beta}^n = z$. We used that $l$ is a $ \log$ branch and $\alpha$ an $n^\text{th}$ root of unity. Thusly, $m$ is also a branch of the logarithm.  One may verify quickly that the function $h: D \to \mathbb C \ z \mapsto \exp(\frac{1}n m(z))$ is a branch of the $n^{th}$ root with $h(a) = b$. and $g = h$ as functions.

Comment: The too long; didn't read is as follows. So long as one starts with a branch $l$ of the logarithm whereby $a$ does not lie on the branch cut, then one can find a suitable constant $\beta \in \frac2n \pi i \mathbb Z$ such that shifting the logarithm branch by said constant will make $m := l + n\beta$ another branch of the logarithm which satisfies the required properties. Details of how to find $\beta$ are contained in the answer.